# GAE Java Project error : javax.mail.Message is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-mail

I keep getting the error "***javax.mail.Message is not supported by Google App Engine's Java runtime environment***" for using Message class and other classes from javax.mail in my GAE java project. I haven't yet found my exact solution for this problem yet, im just assuming its due to my some inconsistencies in JRE System Library and App Engine SDK. Please let me know if anyone has any solution or advice regarding this.

App Engine SDK [App Engine - 1.9.11]
JRE System Library [Java SE 7 [1.7.0_67]]

Answer (score 1):

Did you read [the note here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/) that says :

> Do not add Oracle®'s JavaMail JARs to your app; if you do, the app
>   will throw exceptions.

In eclipse, search for some of the classes from the java mail package (like Transport) and check if they are found in jars outside the GAE SDK or JAVA SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use `javax.mail.Message` in Appengine. It is described here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail

Comment: Yes i have used it in a different GAE project and it was working fine. I just don't know why it is showing not allowing in my current project.